# Can't load a string in XmlDocument

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2.2. I'm getting data from an API which returns XML results. But when MyController wants to load the `text` variable it breaks with this Error

```
IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect : 'I:\Web Development\tamrin\Pizza\Pizza\<ProductType xmlns:i="http:\www.w3.org\2001\XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http:\schemas.datacontract.org\2004\07\MyApi.Core.Models"><Id>2<\Id><Image>\images\burger.png<\Image><Name>Hamburger<\Name><\ProductType>'
```

Here is **MyController**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    { 
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/productTypes/2"))
            {
                string text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                doc.Load(text);      //app breaks here

                doc.Deserialize<ProductType>();
            }
        }
        return View("index");
    }
```

And this is the content of `text` when it is the argument of `doc.load(text)` method.(in debug mode)

```
"<ProductType xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApi.Core.Models\"><Id>2</Id><Image>/images/burger.png</Image><Name>Hamburger</Name></ProductType>"
```

this is the **Deserilize** extension method that I used in MYController (I think it's unnecessary, because the app breaks before it comes to stage)

```
public static class XmlDeserilizer
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XmlDocument document)
        where T : class
    {
        XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(document);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        T result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return result;
    }
}
```

If u need more information just let me know in comments.

Comment: Side note, google "you are using HttpClient wrong".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Load()` expects a file name.
You need to use `LoadXml()`.